# RIP: def route originated locally, trying to block any other route with prefix list-not working

Tags: rip, route-filter

```
ip prefix-list DRoute seq 5 permit 0.0.0.0/0
! since there is an implicit deny the above should allow only the default to 
! pass but it is not happening

router rip
 version 2
 network 10.0.0.0
 default-information originate
 distribute-list DRoute out
 no auto-summary

do sh ip prefix det
Prefix-list with the last deletion/insertion: DRoute
ip prefix-list DRoute:
   count: 1, range entries: 0, sequences: 5 - 5, refcount: 2
   seq 5 permit 0.0.0.0/0 (hit count: 0, refcount: 1)
```

What am I missing here, this should be pretty simple?

Comment: What routes is your neighbor receiving?

Comment: everything including the default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a prefix list, you have to include the word "prefix", like this:

```
distribute-list prefix DRoute out
```

Ref: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/iproute/command/reference/fiprrp_r/1rfrip.html

Comment: that was dumb mistake, I can't belive how much time I wasted with this. Thanks a lot I was starting to doubt my understanding of prefix lists

Comment: Glad you restored your faith ;-p